# Laravel class not found in view

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I call function which user the user controller it works fine but when i call any other function of any other controller it give error that class not found

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\user\UserController' not found
<?php use App\Http\Controllers\user\UserController;
$userCounts = UserController::usercounts();
//print_r($userCounts);?>
```

this is what I am using in my view file and  it work fine when I call any function of user controller. I am calling a user controller function in view.

Comment: Please share the full code. I hope you didn't called controller's method directly in view blade template.

Comment: You should call methods from a model in your views, not from controllers.